# Explanation of fractional sampling in OFDM

Tags: digital-communications, fading-channel, multipath

- What is the concept *fractional sampling*?
- Is there a relationship between the fractional sampling and interpolation?
- And how does the fractional sampling help in convert the SIMO (Signal input multi-output) channel into SISO (single input signal output)?

Comment: These are really three questions, and we should focus on one. Which is the question you want to have answered the most?

Comment: @MarcusMüller is it possible to answer of the three questions ? ...     OK, in that case I prefer having the answer of third one ..

Comment: I would have expected you do not start with the one that requires understanding of both the other ones?

Comment: Ok, answer anyone of them ...  I thought that first two questions can understand them from other friends or search online, but the third, I think it's difficult to get its answer online.

Comment: Well, we *do* expect you to do your own research; I'm hoping a bit for some context of your question, because "fractional sampling" is a rarely used term, and it can mean *rational resampling ratio* and something like *sampling a time signal at fractions of the symbol times* or something similar, so it's hard to give you an answer that is as good as the one you can give yourself - but if you give us some context in which you've read that term, we can try!

Comment: @MarcusMüller .. awaiting for others, they maybe have idea about it.

Comment: ... you could also, you know, just give us some context instead of sitting there doing nothing. Again, it's your responsibility to ask a question that has enough context to be unambiguous. (Voting to close as unclear, will happily retract that vote if you offer enough context.)

Comment: Someone else already answered .. I think his answer is good enough... you voted -1 for the post !!!  I'm sorry to see that here.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first question, you can get enough details in the paper https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/4394307/  , for second question, there is not direct relation but you can read about fractional sampling then you will know the relationship between them. the third question, refer to the paper in link https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/1344460/  .. Just read the two papers and if something still not clear, let me know.

Comment: Thank you very much .. that seems very useful, I will read the details and let you know. thanks again bro

Comment: here is the detailed description for FS-OFDM http://sndgw.snd.elec.keio.ac.jp/~sanada/PUBLICATION/Nishimura.pdf      you are welcome